# Checking cell combination in a table

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to implement an algorithm for table verification, but I'm confused with the multiple choices Ruby supplies for working with arrays and hashes and I need help putting it all together. Consider this table as example:

```
| A | B | C |
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
```

My method should count the number of occurrences of a specific cell combination. For example:

```
match_line([A => 1, C => 3])
```

The results should be `2`, as this combination exists in both the first row and the last one.
What I did so far is to create an `hash` variable that hold column indexing like so:

```
[A => 0, B => 1, C=> 2]
```

And I also have an array list which holds all the above table rows like so:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [5, 6, 7], [1, 1, 3]]
```

The logic looks like that - the `match_line` method above specific the user wants to match a row where column A has the `1` value in it and column C has the `3` value in it. Based on my index hash, the A column index is `0` and C index is `2`. Now for each array (row) in the array list, if index 0 equals `1` and index 2 equals `3` like the user requested , I add +1 to a counter and keep going over the other array row until I'm over.

I tried to form it into code, but I ended with a way that seems very not efficient of doing so, I'm interested to see your code example to see perhaps Ruby has inner Enumerable methods that I'm not aware of to make it more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use the best available structure to describe your domain :

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [5, 6, 7], [1, 1, 3]]

@data_hashes = data.map do |sequence|
  { 'A' => sequence[0], 'B' => sequence[1], 'C' => sequence[2] }
end
```

Second, I think you should use a real Hash as input for match_line :

```
# replace match_line([A => 1, C => 3]) with
match_line({'A' => 1, 'C' => 3})
```

Now you're all set for an easy implementation using `Enumerable#select` and `Array#size` *(or use `Array#count` as pointed by Keith Bennet)*

```
def match_line(match)
  @data_hashes.count { |row|
     match.all? { |match_key, match_value| 
       row[match_key] == match_value
     }
  }
end
```

**EDIT:** Dynamically create Hash from column names

```
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
data = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [5, 6, 7], [1, 1, 3]]

@data_hashes = data.map do |row|
   Hash[columns.zip(row)]
end
```

Comment: This is indeed makes the implementation more easier then mine. I think my error was as you mentioned that my data structure were too complex. The above examples requires my columns to be constants though?  this will not work if the table columns are dynamically picked? I'm guessing I should have another array that holds the column names and somehow build the sequence dynamically against it? Thanks!

Comment: methods should be small and respect some kind of separation of responsibilities : define one method to manage the matching, and another one building the hash from your input. This makes it easier to maintain and reuse.

Comment: Already done. It just I'm not sure how to dynamically assign key value to `@data_hashes`? Something like this perhaps? 

`column_names = ['d', 'e', 'f']
@data_hashes = data.map do |sequence|
  column_names.each_with_index do |value, index| 
  { value => sequence[index] }
end`

Comment: Hash[ [ [key, value], ... ] ] is great for that use. see the edit part above.

Comment: Excellent. I didn't know about the zip method exists. This was very educational for me floum, thank you very much.

Comment: Excellent explanation!  I think you can simplify it a tiny bit by replacing the `select` and `size` with `count`, no?

Comment: One more question regarding the data structure. Reek toss an error about me using Hash key as a string instead of a symbol. But correct me if I'm wrong, there is not better alternative of doing it besides casing all the strings into hash keys on all places?

Comment: You could still call #to_sym on strings with `.map(&:to_sym)`